# GAN training result D loss: nan, acc.: 50% G loss: nan

Tags: python, dataset, tabular, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to implement a GAN to generate network traffic .csv dataset (tabular GAN) and my training result continued to show [D loss: nan, acc.: 50%] [G loss: nan]. I figured that this was because my dataset had NaN values after preprocessing, so I used the code "assert not np.any(np.isnan(x))", and I get the error below. I need help...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5e46f39aeea1> in <module>
      5 #Training the GAN model chosen: Vanilla GAN, CGAN, DCGAN, etc.
      6 synthesizer = model_1(gan_args)
----> 7 synthesizer.train(dataset, train_args)

<ipython-input-26-65296d00d312> in train(self, data, train_arguments)
     72             #  Train Discriminator
     73             # ---------------------
---> 74             batch_data = self.get_data_batch(data, self.batch_size)
     75             noise = tf.random.normal((self.batch_size, self.noise_dim))
     76 

<ipython-input-26-65296d00d312> in get_data_batch(self, train, batch_size, seed)
     56         train_ix = list(train_ix) + list(train_ix)  # duplicate to cover ranges past the end 
of the set
     57         x = train.loc[train_ix[start_i: stop_i]].values
---> 58         assert not np.any(np.isnan(x))
     59         return np.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1))
     60 

AssertionError: `
```

Comment: Ehm, that was what you asked for, no? asserts throw an AssertionError when the condition isn't met. That is exactly what you got. It won't remove the null values by itself, just ensures they are not there. You should remove the null values before running the algorithm

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ken4scholars. I figured it out eventually. Used .dropna(how='any', inplace = True) and it solved the problem. Now my resukt is generating at 93.57% accuracy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out eventually. Used .dropna(how='any', inplace = True) after droping unwanted columns and it solved the problem. Now my result is generating at 93.57% accuracy.